# If $a+\sqrt{b}=c+\sqrt{d}$, is it true that $a=c$ and $b=d$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

> Assume that $a,b,c,d$ are all positive integers. If $a+\sqrt{b}=c+\sqrt{d}$, is it true that $a=c$ and $b=d$?

I am grading some problems and I don't think this true, but all of a sudden I am doubting myself.

Comment: $1+\sqrt 4 =2+\sqrt 1$.

Comment: Observe $$\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{v}\in{\bf Q}\implies \frac{u-v}{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}}\in{\bf Q}\implies\begin{cases}u=v \quad \rm or \\ \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}\in{\bf Q} \implies \sqrt{u},\sqrt{v}\in{\bf Q}\end{cases}$$ The final implication follows from adding and subtracting $\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{v}$ with $\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}$. The converse implications are clear, so we have this if and only if: $$\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{v}~{\rm ~is~rational}\iff u=v~~{\rm or}~~u~{\rm and}~v~\rm are~perfect~squares$$ Note $a+\sqrt{b}=c+\sqrt{d}\iff \sqrt{b}-\sqrt{d}=c-a$ illustrates the relationship to the problem.

Comment: @anon: $\:$ Post that as the answer, because it's better than the other three answers here. $\hspace{.4 in}$

Answer (score 10):

As you can see, there are many counterexamples. I won't add any, except to point out that we have problems when both $b$ and $d$ are perfect squares.

So what we ***can say*** is this: provided at least one of $b, d$ is **not** a perfect square, then yes, $$a + \sqrt b = c + \sqrt d \iff a = c\;\;\text {and} \;\;b = d$$

Comment: I think this answer needs a proof for the last statement to be complete.

Comment: Problems arise only when both $b$ and $d$ are perfect squares (assuming we're restricting nonnegative integers).

Comment: True, @Jonas, I keep thinking of a related problem $a + b\sqrt c = d + e\sqrt f$

Comment: @amWhy: In that case there would be many counterexamples when neither $c$ nor $f$ is a perfect square of course, so thinking of that seems quite different.

Comment: @amWhy: OK, I just meant you could strengthen the statement to say that the uniqueness holds if it is assumed that at least one of $b$ or $d$ is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 8):

If $a+\sqrt{b}=c+\sqrt{d}$, then $(a-c)+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{d}$, so it clearly suffices to study when is it possible to have 
$$a+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{d}.$$
If $b,d$ are arbitrary positive real numbers, then given any $a$ and $b$ such that $a+\sqrt{b}\geq 0$, then there is a $d\geq 0$, namely $d=(a+\sqrt{b})^2$, such that $\sqrt{d}=a+\sqrt{b}$. So I will assume from now on that the OP meant $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $b,d\in \mathbb{Q}^{\geq 0}$.

Suppose $a+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{d}$ holds. Then, by squaring both sides we obtain
$$a^2+2a\sqrt{b} + b = d,$$
If $a=0$, then $b=d$. Otherwise, if $a\neq 0$, then
$$\sqrt{b}=\frac{d-a^2-b}{2a}\in \mathbb{Q}.$$
In particular, $b$ must be a perfect square, and $a+\sqrt{b}\geq 0$.

Conversely, if $b$ is a perfect square, say $b=B^2$ for some $B\geq 0$, so that $B=\sqrt{b}\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $a+\sqrt{b}=a+B\geq 0$, then one can take $d=(a+B)^2$, so that 
$$a+\sqrt{b}=a+B=\sqrt{d}.$$
Hence, $a+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{d}$ has a solution if and only if $b$ is a perfect square, $b=B^2$ for some $B\geq 0$, and $a+B\geq 0$, or $a=0$ and $b=d$.

Thus, $a+\sqrt{b}=c+\sqrt{d}$ has a solution if and only if $b$ is a perfect square, $b=B^2$ for some $B\geq 0$, and $(a-c)+B\geq 0$ (so that $d=((a-c)+B)^2$ is also a perfect square), or $a=c$ and $b=d$.

**Example**: In the example by David Mitra in the comments, 
$$1+\sqrt{4}=2+\sqrt{1}$$
we have $b=4=2^2$, so $B=2$, and $(1-2)+2=1\geq 0$.

Comment: This error is tiny and has no effect on the rest of the argument, but it has been bugging me. After "Suppose $a+\sqrt b=\sqrt d$..." you have $d^2$ on the right hand side of the display equation when it should be $d$ and similarly in the next display equation.

Comment: @user1, thank you for spotting the typo!

Answer (score 1):

a=2 b=4 c=3 d=1 is a counterexample ?

Comment: Yes, this is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect.  For instance, let $a = 1$, $b = 4$, $c = 2$ and $d = 1$ from Mitra's example.  Equality holds, but the corresponding values aren't.  There are more than that counterexample.

Easiest counterexample: Let $a = d = 1$ and $b = c = 0$.  Then, equality holds, but $a \neq c$ and $b \neq d$.

I am pretty sure that you can find another counterexample. ;)